# Javascript adopting image size when dropped

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in the code below I would like to drag an image to the id "centerimg". I've hidden several images cause that's the images who would adopt to the center image. The problem is it doesn't adopt to the size of the center image. It takes the size of the image being dragged. I've tried manipulating its CSS through DOM elements and the only image that changed it's size is the initial image that was dragged.

```js
function doFirst() {
  mypic = document.getElementById('img1');
  mypic.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);

  mypictwo = document.getElementById('img2');
  mypictwo.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag2, false);

  mypicthree = document.getElementById('img3');
  mypicthree.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag3, false);

  mypicfour = document.getElementById('img4');
  mypicfour.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag4, false);

  centerbox = document.getElementById("mainbox");
  centerbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
  centerbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
  centerbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped, false);
}

//--------------startDrag FUNCTIONS -----------------------//
function startDrag(e) {
  var code = '<img id="img1" src="images/ph1.jpg">';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function startDrag2(e) {
  var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/ph2.jpg">';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function startDrag3(e) {
  var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/ph3.jpg">';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function startDrag4(e) {
    var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/ph4.jpg">';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
  }
  //--------------startDrag FUNCTIONS -----------------------//

function dropped(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  centerbox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
}

function drop(event) {

}


window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

```css
 

#centerimg {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

#img2, #img1, #img3, #img4 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

#img5 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.changeimagesize {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="drag.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" id="1box">
        <img id="img1" src="images/image1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="2box">
        <img id="img2" src="images/image2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="3box">
        <img id="img3" src="images/image4.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="4box">
        <img id="img4" src="images/image5.jpg">
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <center>
      <div class="col-md-push-4 col-md-4 mainbox" ondrop="drop(event)" id="mainbox">
        <img id="centerimg" src="images/center.png">
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>

  <!-- hidden images here-->
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph1.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph2.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph3.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph4.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph5.jpg">
  <!--end of hidden images-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution: in the dropped function force the new img tag to get the 500px width and height. In this solution I put width and height hardcoded, but I think there is also the possibility to overcome this.

```js
function doFirst() {
  mypic = document.getElementById('img1');
  mypic.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag, false);

  mypictwo = document.getElementById('img2');
  mypictwo.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag2, false);

  mypicthree = document.getElementById('img3');
  mypicthree.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag3, false);

  mypicfour = document.getElementById('img4');
  mypicfour.addEventListener("dragstart", startDrag4, false);

  centerbox = document.getElementById("mainbox");
  centerbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
  centerbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
  centerbox.addEventListener("drop", dropped, false);
}

//--------------startDrag FUNCTIONS -----------------------//
function startDrag(e) {
  var code = '<img id="img1" src="images/ph1.jpg">';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function startDrag2(e) {
  var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/ph2.jpg">';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function startDrag3(e) {
  var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/ph3.jpg">';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
}

function startDrag4(e) {
    var code = '<img id="img2" src="images/ph4.jpg">';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', code);
  }
  //--------------startDrag FUNCTIONS -----------------------//

function dropped(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  centerbox.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'); console.log(centerbox);
  centerbox.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.width = "500px";
  centerbox.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style.height = "500px";
}

function drop(event) {

}


window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

```css
#centerimg {

   width: 500px;

   height: 500px;

 }

 #img2,

 #img1,

 #img3,

 #img4 {

   width: 150px;

   height: 150px;

 }

 #img5 {

   visibility: hidden;

 }

 .changeimagesize {

   height: 500px;

   width: 500px;

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="drag.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3" id="1box">
        <img id="img1" src="images/image1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="2box">
        <img id="img2" src="images/image2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="3box">
        <img id="img3" src="images/image4.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3" id="4box">
        <img id="img4" src="images/image5.jpg">
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <center>
      <div class="col-md-push-4 col-md-4 mainbox" ondrop="drop(event)" id="mainbox">
        <img id="centerimg" src="images/center.png">
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>

  <!-- hidden images here-->
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph1.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph2.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph3.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph4.jpg">
  <img id="img5" class="img5" src="images/ph5.jpg">
  <!--end of hidden images-->
</body>

</html>
```